# How to run an SQL script

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

When I try to execute all my script the below part is simply ignored. If I execute it separately it work with no issues.

Can you please have a look as I am a n00b and maybe you can see something wrong with this?

Many thanks!

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 
'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/fisier.txt'
INTO TABLE Tabela_veche
CHARACTER SET latin1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '/$/'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '$'
LINES STARTING BY '/' TERMINATED BY '/\n'
(@data_achizitie, @ora_achizitie, nume, prenume, cantitate, 
unitate_masura, piesa)
SET data_achizitie = STR_TO_DATE(@data_achizitie,'%m:%Y:%d'),
    ora_achizitie = replace(@ora_achizitie, ',', '');
```

this is what I have/had just before:

> ```
> DELIMITER $ create trigger fulldate before insert on Tabela_veche for each
>  row begin if new.fulldate is null then set new.fulldate = data_corecta 
>  (new.data_achizitie, new.ora_achizitie); end if; END $
> ```

Comment: You've shared the script but you haven't provided any information about how you're running it, so it's impossible to say what you're doing wrong. Could you please edit the question and include further details?

Comment: Hi! I am executing it with the bolt button. If I execute it in 3 parts (1 before the load, the load and then the rest of the script) it works perfectly. That's why I am thinking that there is something incorrect in the load data infile

Comment: means you are saying above load script individually run fine ,but you run some script before load then it create problem.?

Comment: yes, indeed. It simply ignores it - no warning, no error.
only when I run it all at once

Comment: ithink you have some problem in before load script ,previous script change something in sql and because of this your load script not run .like sometime we change deliminator etc.

Comment: DELIMITER $

create trigger fulldate 
 before insert 
    on Tabela_veche 
    for each row 
begin
 if new.fulldate is null then
  set new.fulldate = data_corecta (new.data_achizitie, new.ora_achizitie);
  end if;
    
END $


this is what I have just before

Comment: do you reset the delimiter before the load data infile and what is data_corecta?

Comment: data_corecta = correct_date -> the date in the txt file is not the right format and this is why I have the trigger

I do not reset the delimiter -> to be honest I don't know how to do that

Comment: You reset the date in the same way you set if ie delimiter ; .Mysql does not have a correct_date function did you write this yourself? Also I would ensure that the trigger works before debugging the load.

Comment: yes, you are right. I removed the trigger and the load now works.

Comment: so now there is another issue. I created the trigger so that the date will be correctly set into the created tables. I don't know what is wrong with it

Comment: how the txt file looks like: /04:2016:27/$/06,54,05/$/Page/$/Bob/$/24/$/Bax/$/Reper 10/

the function for setting the date:
create function data_corecta(d text, t text)
 returns datetime deterministic
  return str_to_date(concat(d, ' ', t),
       '%Y-%m-%d' '%H:%i:%s');

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your error

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(data_achizitie  date,
ora_achizitie time,
fulldate datetime,
nume varchar(100), prenume varchar(100), cantitate varchar(100), 
unitate_masura varchar(100), piesa varchar(100)
);

drop trigger if exists t;

dELIMITER $ 
create trigger t before insert on t
for each row 
begin 
    if new.fulldate is null then 
        set new.fulldate = f(new.data_achizitie,new.ora_achizitie); 
    end if; 
END $ 
delimiter ;

drop function if exists f;
create function f(d text, t text) 
returns datetime deterministic 
return str_to_date(concat(d, ' ', t), '%Y-%m-%d' '%H:%i:%s');

#select f('2019-06-24','06:54:05');


truncate table t;
LOAD DATA INFILE 
'C:\\Program Files\\MariaDB 10.1\\data\\sandbox\\data.txt'
INTO TABLE t
CHARACTER SET latin1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '/$/'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '$'
LINES STARTING BY '/' TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
ignore 1 lines
(@data_achizitie, @ora_achizitie, nume, prenume, cantitate, 
unitate_masura, piesa)
SET data_achizitie = STR_TO_DATE(@data_achizitie,'%m:%Y:%d'),
    ora_achizitie = replace(@ora_achizitie, ',','');

select * from t

+----------------+---------------+---------------------+------+---------+-----------+----------------+------------+
| data_achizitie | ora_achizitie | fulldate            | nume | prenume | cantitate | unitate_masura | piesa      |
+----------------+---------------+---------------------+------+---------+-----------+----------------+------------+
| 2016-04-27     | 06:54:05      | 2016-04-27 06:54:05 | Page | Bob     | 24        | Bax            | Reper 10/  |
+----------------+---------------+---------------------+------+---------+-----------+----------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Please study this and if there any substantive differences between what I am doing to what you are doing add comments.